# (Integral review) $\int_{-1}^1 \int_1^{e^x}\frac{x}{y} \, dy \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve this integral changing the order of integration, but my integral doesn't touch region in $[-1,0)$ tru?

$$D=\left \{  x,y\in \mathbb{R}: -1\leq x\leq 1,1\leq y\leq e^x  \right \}$$

So, my question is: Should I solve it as is? or should I write it like this
$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_1^{e^x}\frac{x}{y} \, dy \, dx=\text{?}\int_0^1 \int_1^{e^x}\frac{x}{y} \, dy\, dx$$
therefore changing the order

$$D'=\left \{  x,y\in \mathbb{R}: \ln(y)\leq x\leq 1,1\leq y\leq e  \right \}$$

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, what is the original problem? is it the integral itself or the problem asked you to chance of variables? or region

Comment: @Valerin Sorry for my bad writing.
My problem is the original integral, should I integrate it as in the intervals that give me?
It is that when graphing it, I noticed that y> 1, but I think the region that I must integrate does not make sense because it does not pass through x <0

Comment: @Valerin this is original $ \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{1}^{e^x}\frac{x}{y}dydx$

Comment: You'll want to draw a picture for this one. You should notice that your lower bound is larger than your upper bound on your inner integral when $-1\leq x <0$

Comment: @MatthewPilling Sorry I did not understand. Could you explain me in more detail please. :C

Comment: If $x\in [-1,0)$ then $e^x$ is smaller than $1$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling So? How do I solve the original integral? :c 
$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{1}^{e^x}\frac{x}{y}dydx$

Comment: I don't see that changing the order makes sense in this case. You have $$ \int_1^{e^x} \frac x y \, dy = \Big[ x\ln y\Big]_{y\,:=\,1}^{y\,:=\,e^x} = x\ln(e^x) - x\ln 1 = x\cdot x - 0. $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy $x\ln(e^x)=x^{2}$ ? Yeah, but my problem is in $x \in [-1,0]$. Thank You <3

Comment: @davidhernandez What I wrote above does not depend on whether $x>0$ or $x<0. \qquad$